# how can i disable label or label from ib after displaying text on to it

Tags: iphone, uilabel

hi i would like to ask one intresting question 
i should disable or remove label from my view when certain event ocuurs
how can i disable it can any one give me a syntax for that one
i hope i will get answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in your program just use `label.hidden = YES` or `label.enabled = NO` if you want just to make it unclickable (while keeping its text, also if dimmed)